# How to iterate through a list of LEDs in ARM AT91SAM7S256 Microcontoller using C Language

Tags: c, arm, embedded, microcontroller

I am writing a code for the ARM AT91SAM7S256 Microcontoller. I am trying to turn on the LED randomly.

Up until now, I have initialised the LEDS in an array.

My array is

```
short leds [] = {LED1, LED2, LED3, LED4, LED5, LED6, LED7, LED8};
```

The code line to set the led on is

```
SetLEDcolor(LEDNumber, RED);
```

The value of `LEDNumber` should come randomly from the array.

Comment: Can you turn each LED on/off in a *non-random* way? For example by iterating through the array, with a delay.

Comment: What OS or hardware abstraction library do you use? If it is not a well-known OS, show (a link to) the description of a random number generator function.

Comment: So you have an array and a function. What have you actually done so far? How are the LEDs defined? How do you handle GPIO? Indeed can you light a LED without randomness? Are you asking how to light LEDs or how to implement randomzation? Is this with or without ASF? Hosted or bare metal?

Comment: yes that is going on with for loop.... but i need a random value from the array... like for example led7 should turn on.... then when i try again led3 should turn on

Answer (score 1):

```
srand(time(NULL));

int ix = rand() % (sizeof(leds)/sizeof(*leds));
SetLEDcolor(leds[ix], RED);
```

Comment: What makes you think `time()` is available for a generic microcontroller? There's no generally no RTC available, and if there is you'll have to use a custom lib to handle it. Because a microcontroller isn't a PC.

Comment: Because on most microcontrollers `time()` is not available in any sane way, some people just `srand(<some random number chosen arbitrary>)`. A semi-good way is to read some hardware register with Device ID or Chip ID or Device Revision or similar and pass that value to `srand` to initialize the _pseudo_-random generator.